# send method in Browser Client generates error in Flutter Web application

Tags: flutter, dart

The following function is called on press of a button in Flutter App:

```
void save() async {
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
  var requestBody = {
    'name': nameController.text,
    'address1': address1Controller.text,
    'address2': address2Controller.text,
    'city': cityController.text,
    'zipcode': zipcodeController.text,
    'state': dropdownValue,
    'phone': phoneController.text,
    'fax': faxController.text,
    'email': emailController.text,
    'url': urlController.text,
    'contact': contactController.text,
  };
  var sendString = jsonEncode(requestBody);
  print(sendString);
  //post it to server
    final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://localhost:9090/employers/nameAddress'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'ContentType': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: sendString,
  );
  
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      var decoded = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var item in decoded) {
        print(item);
      }
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to post data');
    }
  }
}
```

}

The sendString value is printed as follows:

```
{"name":"MyCompany","address1":"100 main ","address2":"Apt 202","city":"Lakeland","zipcode":"34543","state":"Arkansas","phone":"8889998898","fax":"fax345","email":"email@a.c","url":"myco.com","contact":"Bob"}
```

The debugger stops in the send function below in the browser_client.dart file at completer.completeError line shown below.

```
/// Sends an HTTP request and asynchronously returns the esponse.
@override
Future<StreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {
var bytes = await request.finalize().toBytes();
var xhr = HttpRequest();
_xhrs.add(xhr);
xhr
  ..open(request.method, '${request.url}', async: true)
  ..responseType = 'arraybuffer'
  ..withCredentials = withCredentials;
request.headers.forEach(xhr.setRequestHeader);

var completer = Completer<StreamedResponse>();

unawaited(xhr.onLoad.first.then((_) {
  var body = (xhr.response as ByteBuffer).asUint8List();
  completer.complete(StreamedResponse(
      ByteStream.fromBytes(body), xhr.status!,
      contentLength: body.length,
      request: request,
      headers: xhr.responseHeaders,
      reasonPhrase: xhr.statusText));
}));

unawaited(xhr.onError.first.then((_) {
  // Unfortunately, the underlying XMLHttpRequest API doesn't expose any
  // specific information about the error itself.
  completer.completeError(     <<-----------------program stops here
      ClientException('XMLHttpRequest error.', request.url),
      StackTrace.current);
}));

xhr.send(bytes);

try {
  return await completer.future;
} finally {
  _xhrs.remove(xhr);
}
```

}

Continuing the program dumps the following error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 909:28    get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 71:22        <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1613:54               runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18         handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44         handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 533:           [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14 
_checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37307:58                              <fn>
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:5054:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37670:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback 
(http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37666:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37526:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:37532:13)
at http://localhost:53992/dart_sdk.js:33303:9
```

The same data sent using Postman returns server message: "Field Date Registered is required!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used BrowserClient for post transaction.
Also added CORS headers on server to fixe the issue.